# Replacing missing values with a lagged value in a vector read in from an Excel file

Tags: r

```
 Animal ID
1      38-L
2      <NA>
3      39-L
4      <NA>
5      40-L
6      <NA>
etc.
```

I'm reading the above data in from an Excel spreadsheet. I then want to remove -L and -R from the vector, convert to numeric and replace the missing values with the number immediately from above.

My code is as follows:

```
SugarData <- as.data.frame(read_excel(InFile[2], sheet = "Data for stats (+RN) (+FA)", range = "D1:D161"))
head(SugarData)
BirdNumber <- as.numeric(str_replace_all(SugarData[, 1], "[-LR]", ""))
for (i in seq(1, length(BirdNumber) - 1, by = 2)) {
  BirdNumber[i + 1] <- BirdNumber[i]
}
SugarData[1] <- BirdNumber
```

This works but my problem is two-fold.

When I read this in as a tibble the str_replace_all function doesn't work as I expected and I think that maybe there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Hope someone can help.

Regards,
Alan.

My main problem is that when I read the data in as a tibble and then use:

```
BirdNumber <- str_replace_all(SugarData[, 1], "[-LR]", "")
```

I get the following:

```
"c(\"38\", NA, \"39\", NA, \"40\", NA, \"41\", NA, \"42\", NA, \"44\", NA, \"45\", NA, \"46\", NA, \"49\", NA, \"53\", NA, \"158\", NA, \"159\", NA, \"161\", NA, \"163\", NA, \"164\", NA, \"166\", NA, \"167\", NA, \"168\", NA, \"169\", NA, \"170\", NA, \"398\", NA, \"400\", NA, \"401\", NA, \"403\", NA, \"404\", NA, \"405\", NA, \"407\", NA, \"408\", NA, \"409\", NA, \"410\", NA, \"521\", NA, \"522\", NA, \"523\", NA, \"524\", NA, \"525\", NA, \"526\", NA, \"527\", NA, \"529\", NA, \"530\", NA, \"533\", \nNA, \"578\", NA, \"580\", NA, \"581\", NA, \"582\", NA, \"584\", NA, \"585\", NA, \"588\", NA, \"589\", NA, \"590\", NA, \"593\", NA, \"602\", NA, \"605\", NA, \"606\", NA, \"607\", NA, \"608\", NA, \"609\", NA, \"610\", NA, \"611\", NA, \"612\", NA, \"616\", NA, \"702\", NA, \"705\", NA, \"706\", NA, \"707\", NA, \"708\", NA, \"709\", NA, \"710\", NA, \"711\", NA, \"712\", NA, \"713\", NA, \"821\", NA, \"822\", NA, \"823\", NA, \"824\", NA, \"826\", NA, \"827\", NA, \"828\", NA, \"830\", NA, \"831\", \nNA, \"832\", NA)"
```

Comment: Share a small sample of your data by copy-paste output of `dput(data)` - probably `dput(head(SugarData))` should work...

Comment: As requested:structure(list(`Animal ID` = c("38-L", NA, "39-L", NA, "40-L", 
NA, "41-L", NA, "42-L", NA)), .Names = "Animal ID", row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

You are using `str_replace_all` which returns list, you should try to use `str_replace` instead, you can also use `gsub` from base R.

```
library(stringr)
zoo::na.locf(as.numeric(str_replace(dat$`Animal ID`,"-(L|R|LR)$","")))
```

**Logic**:

`str_replace` will find the pattern basis the 'Animal ID' column with the given regex. Conversion is done using `as.numeric` and then replacing the missing values by last non missing value above rows using `zoo` package's `locf`(last observation carry forward) function.

**Data as per OP given in comments:**

```
structure(list("Animal ID" = c("38-L", NA, "39-L", NA, "40-L", NA, "41-L", NA, "42-L", NA)), .Names = "Animal ID", row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Output**:

```
> zoo::na.locf(as.numeric(str_replace(dat$`Animal ID`,"-(L|R|LR)$","")))
 [1] 38 38 39 39 40 40 41 41 42 42
```